# How to use model function result in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an error in my controller. I am trying to use the result coming from model function to call another function in my model. I am using Codeigniter Framework. hope you can help me out. Thanks

Controller:

```
function photographer_campaign_details(){

        $camp_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $data['page_title'] = 'Photographer Campaign Details';
        $adminId = $this->session->userdata('adminid');
        $campaign = $this->Admin_model->get_all_photographer_campaign_details($camp_id);

        $data['seller'] = $this->Admin_model->get_seller_name_by_id($campaign['uid']);//error is here: Undefined index: uid
        $data['campaign'] = $campaign;
        $this->load->view('admin/photographer_campaign_details',$data);

}
```

My Model:

```
function get_all_photographer_campaign_details($camp_id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('campaign_id',$camp_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('ps_campaigns');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return array();
    }
    //get seller name by id
    function get_seller_name_by_id($uid)
    {
        $this->db->select('firstname, lastname');
        $this->db->where('id', $uid);
        $query = $this->db->get('ps_users');
        //return $query->row();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
```

an error is coming from the controller: Undefined index: uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `get_all_photographer_campaign_details`, if no rows are found then you return an empty array.

In your controller, you never check to see if a valid entry was found.  As a result you get your `undefined index: uid` when an id is referenced in the URL that doesn't correspond to an entry, because `$campaign` is empty and doesn't have a `uid` key.  Try something like this:

```
function photographer_campaign_details(){

        $camp_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $data['page_title'] = 'Photographer Campaign Details';
        $adminId = $this->session->userdata('adminid');
        $campaign = $this->Admin_model->get_all_photographer_campaign_details($camp_id);
        if (!$campaign ){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['seller'] = $this->Admin_model->get_seller_name_by_id($campaign['uid']);//error is here: Undefined index: uid
        $data['campaign'] = $campaign;
        $this->load->view('admin/photographer_campaign_details',$data);

}
```

Additionally, you are returning data wrong in the event that you **do** find data.  Namely this bit in `get_all_photographer_campaign_details`:

```
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
```

Should be something like:

```
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $data = $row;
            break;
        }
```

The problem is that you are appending the row as one row in `$data`, but your controller is expecting to get the actual data itself.  I.e. your controller is expecting this:

```
[
    'campaignid' => 1,
    'uid' => 'ijerjeire'
]
```

But you are returning this:

```
[
    [
        'campaignid' => 1,
        'uid' => 'ijerjeire'
    ]
]
```

Note the extra array that everything is wrapped around.  Basically, your model is returning an array of results, when your controller is just expecting results.  My above suggestion will work if there is only ever supposed to be one campaign returned.  If that is not the case, then you need to adjust your controller instead of your model method.

To reiterate my other point: make sure and validate the user input that comes from the URL.  Otherwise you will return PHP errors instead of 404's.

Comment: I am getting all the campaign details correctly, I just want to do another query to get name and show it instead of uid.

Comment: Why do you believe you are getting all your campaign details correctly?  Your error clearly shows that the `uid` key in the `$campaign` variable doesn't exist.  Most likely reason for that is because no record was found.  That will absolutely happen anyway, because the id is coming in from the URL and is therefore user input, which you are not validating.  A user can put whatever number (or not-number) they want in your URL, in which case your query will find no campaign, and this error will happen.  You have to validate your inputs.

Comment: I am doing testing on one campaign only and I have all values correctly shown in my view. but I am trying to show text instead of user id.  I just want to know how can I access uid from $campaign if I use $query->result_array() in my first model function which is (get_all_photographer_campaign_details)? Thanks

Comment: You've got two bugs.  I edited my answer to discuss the second.  To be clear, the other issue I mentioned is also a bug: just because you don't see the effects of it in your current test doesn't mean that it won't cause trouble later.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everything is working fine now and I will consider your note and fix the first bug also, thanks for reminding me about that :)